# How to create requests dialog with multiple recipients selected by app

Tags: javascript, facebook-javascript-sdk

The Sims Social has their own friend selector. And once you select your friends and hit submit, it throws up this official Facebook request dialog that has multiple friends on it and a checkbox that says "Don't ask before sending The Sims Social requests to..."

How can I duplicate this? I've tried sending an array to the apprequests ui dialog, but that gives "Error Message: Too many recipients."

[image]

I'm not using the Facebook friend selector. I'm using my own and sending it to the apprequests dialog. The Sims does this, I just can't reproduce it.

```
FB.ui({
    method: 'apprequests',
    message: 'Send a gift',
    data: {},
    title: "Send a gift",
    to: uids[0] + "," + uids[1]
});
```

I've tried the to field with a string list, "1234,4567". I've tried it with an array { 1234, 4567 }. But neither works. An array with a single UID works fine. But multiple UIDs gives "Error Message: Too many recipients."

Comment: `{}` represents an object literal, not an array. `[]` represents an array.

Comment: please, can you tell me how did you send the request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you need to be whitelisted by Facebook to get this sort of super power. The Sims Social are using the same parameters as you do but have the ability to specify multiple recipients. You should ask Facebook to do the same for your app.

Comment: please, can you tell me how did you send the request?

Comment: I would also be interested to know. I'm having the same exact problem.

Answer (score 2):

As per the [Facebook documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/) (which admittedly isn't very good), you can pass a JavaScript array, `[]`, in the `to` attribute. It looks like `uids` is already an array, so try this:

```
FB.ui({
    method: 'apprequests',
    message: 'Send a gift',
    data: {},
    title: "Send a gift",
    to: uids
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the Requests Dialog - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/

You can have up to 50 recipients per request (some restrictions on IE, as mentioned in the doc).

With multiple IDs, you can specify the recipients in the 'to' parameter as a JavaScript array, e.g. 'to: [1,2,3]'

Comment: That is what I'm doing, but I cannot get the request confirmation box to accept multiple UIDs.

Comment: The 'to' field takes a JavaScript array, so you must have square brackets around the IDs: to: [1,2,3]

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Improvements to Request 2.0](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/569/) thread posted September 29, 2011

> You can specify an array of user_ids in the ‘to’ field of the request
>   dialog.

```
  function sendRequestToManyRecipients() {
    var user_ids = document.getElementsByName("user_ids")[0].value;
    FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
      message: 'My Great Request',
      to: user_ids,
    }, requestCallback);
  }
```